# How to add header value for firebase realtime database js file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, http-headers, cross-origin-resource-policy

I am having an issue with my site regarding Firebase Realtime Database and Cross Origin Resource Policy. My site already has The Cross Origin Resource Policy header configured and is being served on every asset in my site (js, css, html, etc). But now the js script from firebase.io is being blocked because it doesn't have this header.
I would like to ask, how do I add these headers? Where in the Firebase console should I go to?

[image: Screenshot of blocked script]

Here is the piece of code where the issue is triggered. Basically I initialize the `Server` object then call `changeDb,` then call **checkAuthor** (Where the issue occurs):

```js
window.Server = function () {
  const config = {
    apiKey: FirebaseApiKey,
    authDomain: FirebaseAuthDomain,
    projectId: FirebaseProjectId,
    storageBucket: FirebaseStorageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: FirebaseMessagingSenderId,
    appId: FirebaseAppId,
    databaseURL: FirebaseDatabaseUrl
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
};

Server.prototype.changeDb = function (prefix) {
  this.annotationsRef = firebase.database().ref().child(prefix + '/annotations');
  this.authorsRef = firebase.database().ref().child(prefix + '/authors');
}

Server.prototype.checkAuthor = function (authorId, openReturningAuthorPopup, openNewAuthorPopup) {
  this.authorsRef.once('value', authors => {  //<== Here is where it is triggered
    if (authors.hasChild(authorId)) {
      this.authorsRef.child(authorId).once('value', author => {
        openReturningAuthorPopup(author.val().authorName);
      });
    } else {
      openNewAuthorPopup();
    }
  });
};
```

[image: Call stack for blocked request]

Comment: Are you using the REST API? Can you please share your code.

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj I updated the question with code and screenshot of the call stack for the blocked request